# ES6 JS: syntax for const export when there is some recursion

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have the following code that works:

```
import sequelize from 'sequelize';
let A = sequelize.define('a', {
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      someMethod(foo) {
        return A.upsert(foo);
      }
    }
  });

export default A;
```

However, I would like to put the `export default` on the same line that the definition of `A` for clarity. However, since some part of `A` basically calls itself I'm not able to find out what the right syntax could be.

Comment: Please do not bug me on the purpose of someMethod: this is an example.

Comment: How about simply using `this.upsert` without `A`?

Comment: @Bergi The content of "someMethod" is just an example to show my point

Comment: Regardless, I just wanted to point out that you might be able to refer to `A` by using `this` or `this.constructor`. If not, you have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @Bergi ...and you are right: this works and solves my issue in an elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
export { A as default }
const A = …; // whatever
```

or

```
let A; // I would avoid this
export default A = …;
```

There is no shortcut, `export default` works only with function or class declarations.

Comment: can't manage your first syntax: I get a `ReferenceError: A is not defined`. Your second syntax obviously works, that's the one I have in the example above that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: Really? I'm pretty sure it's legit. Are you using a transpiler? If yes, it might be a bug.

Comment: Regarding the second syntax, no, it's not the same as in your question; you are doing `const A = …; export default A;` there - in my snippet, the "`export default`" keyword is above the definition.

Comment: On the first syntax: yes, babel transpiler. On the second syntax, you are right, I overlooked the details.

Comment: @GurgHackpof Ah, there it is: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4567

Comment: And there you go, I just used your (second) syntax because your `this` trick didn't cut it for this particular example. I'm awarding you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you can't.

The long answer is: when doing `export default something` you are specifying that a given value will be exported from the module and is intrinsically nameless (hence, the `default` part).

Unlike with CommonJS, you don't have a handle for whatever you're exporting. What you're wanting to do is equivalent to calling an anonymous function recursively. How could you do that without a reference?